# What is the factorization on $\mathbb{F}_4$ of an irreducible polynomial of $\mathbb{F}_2 [X]$ of degree $4$?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Show that all irreducible polynomial of $\mathbb{F}_2 [X]$ of degree $4$ factored  on $\mathbb{F}_4$ into a product of $2$ irreducible polynomials of degree $2$:

I see that any polynomial $P$ of $\mathbb{F}_2 [X]$ of degree $4$, irreducible on $\mathbb{F}_2$, has a root in $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ which is an extension of degree $2$ of $\mathbb{F}_4$. Then $P$ is reducible on $\mathbb{F}_4$. It remains to show that $P$ does not admit a root in $\mathbb{F}_4$. This is my Problem.

Comment: it may be easiest to first list the irreducible polynomials up to degree $4$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. Here is up to degree $3$ to get you started $x,x+1,x^2+x+1,x^3+x+1,x^3+x^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to double check my work. I think all the degree $4$ irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ are

$$
x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1,\quad x^4+x^3+1,\quad x^4+x+1.
$$

Over $\mathbb{F}_4$, all three polynomials have no roots so if they are reducible then they must factor into products of degree $2$ irreducibles in $\mathbb{F}_4[x]$. I leave it to you to write down these irreducibles and check.